# Raspbian - new created user cannot perform rised privilegies action from GUI

Tags: raspbian

Using raspbian (4.4.13+) I created a new user to replace the default "pi". It belongs to the same groups that pi is (adm, dialout, cdrom, sudo, audio, video, plugdev, games, input, netdev, gpio, i2c and spi).

The new user work correctly and using "sudo" it can do everything.

BUT if I would like to perform an action with raised privileges from GUI (example: add/remove software) the only prompted allowed identities are "root" and "pi". No way to select a different one.

Obviously I miss something, but I don't know where to look.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Check `/etc/sudoers`. This normally ends with `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Adding your new user might help.

Comment: in addition to what @Milliways stated, it's highly advisable to use the `visudo` command to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, as it'll catch syntax errors, which if allowed to go through, could break many things (I've found this out the hard way)

Comment: @Milliways adding it to the `/etc/sudoers/` doesn't change the situation. The new user belong to the `sudo` group, so the edit should be unnecessary due to the line `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. Please note that form command line everything is working fine, the problems rise only form GUI.